# while rotating around Y in Transform, it rotates around Z in Viewport Is it a bug in Unreal Engine 5.3?

Tags: transformation, unreal-5, rigging

I struggle to understand how the transfomartion is working in Unreal. I've faced one interesting situation and cannot realize what happed. Could somebody explain please why my rig is rotating around Z axis when I'm rotating it around Y?
I am sure there are no any blueprint nodes or backend logic which could lead to this behavior.

[image]

**Update.** During last night I’ve got a few ideas how it is working. I still don’t know what exactly brought this type of behavior . But I know how to fix it. Just recreate same rig again.

While it is no longer critical question for me, I would be really appreaciated if somebody brings some tips how to avoid that type of behavior in the future.
Or are there some golden rules how to work with offset and transforms in UE?

Thanks